# How to set a toolbar to be fixed in the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I have a linearView with cardViews and some other elements.
The view with all it's elements is scrallable.
I'm trying to add a fixed toolbar in the bottom of the screen by wrapping everything in RelativeView and using alignParentBottom on the layout of my toolbar, but The toolbar is added to the bottom of the scrallable page ( you need to scroll all the way down to see it.

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_poi_detail_main_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar_image" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/fragment_poi_detail_line"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_shadow_height"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_shadow"/>

        <include
            layout="@layout/fragment_poi_detail_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fragment_poi_detail_card_margin_vertical_first"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fragment_poi_detail_card_margin_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fragment_poi_detail_card_margin_horizontal_first"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fragment_poi_detail_card_margin_horizontal_last"/>

        <include
            layout="@layout/fragment_poi_detail_content_info"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fragment_poi_detail_card_margin_vertical_first"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fragment_poi_detail_card_margin_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fragment_poi_detail_card_margin_horizontal_first"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fragment_poi_detail_card_margin_horizontal_last"/>

        <include
            layout="@layout/fragment_poi_detail_content_banner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fragment_poi_detail_card_margin_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fragment_poi_detail_card_margin_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fragment_poi_detail_card_margin_horizontal_first"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fragment_poi_detail_card_margin_horizontal_last" />

        <include
            layout="@layout/fragment_poi_detail_content_map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fragment_poi_detail_card_margin_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fragment_poi_detail_card_margin_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fragment_poi_detail_card_margin_horizontal_first"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fragment_poi_detail_card_margin_horizontal_last" />

        <include
            layout="@layout/fragment_poi_detail_content_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fragment_poi_detail_card_margin_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fragment_poi_detail_card_margin_vertical_last"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fragment_poi_detail_card_margin_horizontal_first"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fragment_poi_detail_card_margin_horizontal_last" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <include layout="@layout/fragment_poi_detail_bottom_action_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >
    </include>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your help :)

[image: !]

This is the view scrolled to bottom, and the bar in the bottom of the view.

Comment: I don't see a scrolling `View` in that layout. If that layout is included in another layout with the scrolling `View`, your toolbar needs to be in that other layout, outside of the scrolling `View`.

Comment: There is no scrolling view. There is a Linear view that includes a few cardViews (fragment_poi_detail_header, fragment_poi_detail_content_info, fragment_poi_detail_content_banner, etc.. ) making it long.
This is the view that can be scrolled.

Comment: If you can scroll, then there is a scrolling `View`. Anyway, whatever the layout you've posted is contained in, that's where you need to move your toolbar.